# Beautiful soup missing some html table tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract data from a website using beautiful soup to parse the html. I'm currently trying to get the table data from the following webpage :

[link to webpage](http://www.installationsclassees.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/ficheEtablissement.php?selectRegion=-1&selectDept=-1&champcommune=&champNomEtabl=&selectRegSeveso=-1&selectRegEtab=-1&selectPrioriteNat=-1&selectIPPC=-1&champActivitePrinc=-1&champListeIC=&selectDeclaEmi=&champEtablBase=544&champEtablNumero=18&ordre=&champNoEnregTrouves=4480&champPremierEnregAffiche=0&champNoEnregAffiches=20)

I want to get the data from the table. First I save the page as an html file on my computer (this part works fine, I checked that I got all the information) but when I try to parse with the following code :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(fh, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table') 
cols = table[0].find_all('tr')
cells = cols[1].find_all('td')`
```

I don't get any results (specifically it crashes, saying there's no element at index 1). Any idea of where it could come from?

Thanks

Comment: Works for me as is, are you sure you are parsing the correct HTML file?

Comment: I see a space between `table` and `[0]` on the 3rd line. On the other hand, I had a similar issue earlier and I found out that when the html is much drilled down, Beautiful Soup can't handle it. I've tried different `html parsers` but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: I'm quite sure I'm parsing the correct HTML file, at least when I open it in notepad it looks correct.
About the space it was a typo sorry, but not present in my code.

Comment: It works for me too. What do you got when you type `print(len(cols))` ? It should be 3.

Answer (score 0):

Ok actually it was an issue in the html file, in the first line the html tags were opened with th but closed with td. I don't know much about HTML but replacing the th by td solved the issue.

```
<tr class="listeEtablenTete">
<th title="Rubrique IC">Rubri. IC</td>
<th title="Alin&eacute;a">Ali.&nbsp;</td>
<th title="Date d'autorisation">Date auto.</td>
<th >Etat d'activit&eacute;</td>
<th title="R&eacute;gime">R&eacute;g.</td>
<th >Activit&eacute;</td>
<th >Volume</td>
<th >Unit&eacute;</td>`
```

Thanks !